# What's up with the task.uploadsummary and task.logissue commands in the new VSTS RM UI?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In the new VSTS RM UI that is rolling out, I'm no longer able to see or otherwise access summary attachments published to the release through the ##vso[task.uploadsummary] command. Is support for this command being deprecated in the new UI?

I've also noticed that messages posted with ##vso[task.logissue] don't end up anywhere outside of the logs tab, whereas they used to be present on the summary page:

[Old warnings / errors output on summary page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dixFj.png)

When I'm in the pipeline tab as the environment finishes, I can see "*n* issues" come up for an environment where an agent made n calls to ##vso[task.logissue], but it seems like this "*n* issues" message disappears when I reload the release - so those warnings/errors would be buried to someone coming to the release for the first time:

["11 issues" is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyn9I.png)

["11 issues" has disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTxoP.png)

Note that the fact that there were 11 "issues" and 11 failed tests is a coincidence.

The ##vso[task.logissue type=error;] command places the error message under the task that generated it in the tests tab (without needing to open the logs in the full view), which is something, but this isn't the case for warnings:

[Error message show up on top in logs tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76TTt.png)

[Warning messages only show up in the logs themselves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ukxh.png)

For ##vso[task.logissue], is this the new UI experience we should expect, or is this possibly an oversight? I think it'd be ideal if independent counts of warnings and errors were listed where "*n* Issues" showed up above, and that these would be clickable such that and the list of each would come up in the pane on the right side of the pipeline tab when you select an environment.

Comment: Is this issue occurs on the new releases? I mean create new release definition, check that again.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Andy. I'm seeing this for release definitions that existed before the new UI, so yes I can try creating a new one. Can I export / import the old one, or should I start from scratch in the UI?

Comment: I suggest you creating new release definition, as you said start from scratch in the UI.

Comment: Went ahead and gave that a try, but I'm seeing all the same UI behavior. The behavior isn't necessarily bad, just different enough from the old UI that it we'll need to rethink how we're using the aforementioned commands (especially for task.uploadsummary, which doesn't seem to do anything in the new UI). Do you think what I'm seeing is the intended experience going forward?

Comment: I think it should be the the intended experience going forward, however if you don't want such experiences you can submit [user voices](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) to suggest the feature.

Comment: +10 for this question. In a recently upgraded TFS 2018 installation, I have encountered the same behavior (`##[task.uploadsummary]` no longer shown on build result), and was worrying I had messed up my Inline Powershell job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting issue and providing feedback to make our product better. There are bunch of issues reported in the above post, please see my answer below.

1. **##vso[task.uploadsummary] command not working** – This is in our backlog and we’ll pick it up asap.
2. **Showing issues at the top level** – This is also in our backlog and currently we are working on the right experience, hopefully it will come in upcoming release.
3. **Issue message disappears when I reload the release** – We are investigating the issue.
4. **Warning not showing up in the logs tab, only show up in the logs** – This we have already fixed it and it will roll out with upcoming production deployment.
5. **Show counts of warnings and errors instead of n issues** – This we have already fixed it and it will roll out with upcoming production deployment.